# How to pass manytomany PKs to post or put

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, postman

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Track.objects.all(), )

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

what is the format for adding multiple tracks

tracks is a manytomany field

tried array, comma separated but no luck

If I pass

```
track = "Track1"
```

where "Track1" is the primary key of Track 1

How to add `['Track1', 'Track2']`

Actual code

```
class TreatmentTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    icds = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=False, many=True, queryset=ICD_10.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Treatment_template
```

---

**Screenshot 1**

[image]

Postman supports array in above format??

---

**Screenshot 2**

[image]

---

**Screenshot 3**

[image]

Comment: if it some thing related to https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/971

Comment: Could you update your question to what you have tried and which errors you get? Because basically what you write is correct. You pass them as a list of primary keys, e.g. `tracks = [1, 3, 5]` which translates to JSON as `"tracks": [1,3,5]`.

Answer (score 6):

**Sending plain JSON objects**

I would suggest testing complex request data (including arrays or nested objects) by directly sending `JSON` rather than `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded`. To do this click on `raw` and paste your `JSON` object there.

To get a well-formatted JSON object to start with I usually first issue a `GET` request for a resource that already exists. Then I can just copy the response, change the request method to `PUT`, click the `raw` button and paste the json. Then I can start modifying the object and test the endpoint.

In the example above, does the following work?

```
{
  "uuid": "the-long-uuid-here",
  "icds": [
    "A00",
    "A001"
  ]
}
```

---

**Update: Put multiple m2m ids with x-www-form-urlencoded**

As I wasn't completely happy with not providing an alternative I tested a bit more (with the latest Postman which looks differently).

You can pass multiple values using `x-www-form-urlencoded`. To do that, add multiple rows with the same label `icds` and one value at a time.

Notice that I tested it with an endpoint that provides `books`, which would be `icds` in your use case. The data in the screenshot will be transmitted as `books=1&books=3&last_name=foobar` which gets correctly picked up by the DRF endpoint.

**Screenshot Postman**

[image: Posting with x-www-form-urlencoded]

Comment: `x-www-form-urlencoded` was just what I needed to allow POSTing multiple Values having the same Key name.